# Variance of Portfolio

Tags: random-variables, variance

## Setup

Let variables $X$ and $Y$ to be the returns on two assets that following some unknown distributions and $Z = w_x * X + w_y * Y$ to be the return of a portfolio, with proportion $w_x$ and $w_y$ invested in $X$ and $Y$ respectively.

Now by basic property of variance we have (1)
$$Var(Z) = w_x^2 Var(X) + w_y^2Var(Y) + 2w_xw_yCov(X, Y)$$

## Problem

If we have two vectors $\textbf{x}$ and $\textbf{y}$ representing the historical returns of the two assets, then it follows that $\textbf{z} = w_x\textbf{x} + w_y\textbf{y}$ is the historical return of the portfolio.

If we want to estimate $Var(Z)$ based on the historical information, there are two possible ways.

1. Using formula (1) by estimating $Var(X)$, $Var(Y)$, $Cov(X, Y)$ with sample statistics $var(\textbf{x})$, $var(\textbf{y})$, and $cov(\textbf{x}, \textbf{y})$.
2. Calculating the sample variance directly from $\textbf{z}$.

According to this [blog post](https://blog.quantopian.com/markowitz-portfolio-optimization-2/), when estimating the variance of a portfolio, one should always use the first method. While I can understand why the first method is correct, I fail to see why the second is incorrect.

Afterall, $\textbf{z}$ is a sample of $Z$. Why cannot we just estimate the population variance directly from sample variance?